# Python UDP server receives / outputs every character multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Trying to understand the networking with python. So, I took a small task to stream(send) characters onto server as i type. There is a strange behaviour I don't seem to understand here. I type/send one character , but the server receives it multiple times. I am using the Keyboard package to catch the global(outside of my application) keystroke events.

There is successful communication established. However, every keystroke repeats twice at least.
Attached below is the output and as well as the codes on server and client sides. What is it i am missing?

[image]

**server.py**

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serversocket.bind(ADDR)
print("[STARTING] server is starting...")

while True:
    print("[WAITING]...")
    (data, addr) = serversocket.recvfrom(HEADER)
    print(f"[{addr}] {data}")
```

**client.py**

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client.connect(ADDR)
client.send("REQUESTING SERVICES...")

keystrokeslisten = True
while (keystrokeslisten):
    key_read = keyboard.read_key()
    data_message = key_read.encode(FORMAT)
    client.send(data_message)
```

Comment: `keyboard.read_key()` does not do what you expect it to, your loop is running faster than you think.

Comment: You may be right about the loop, But I don't know how to fix it . About the Keyboard.read_key() though, It seems to catch all the keystrokes outside of the Terminal as well . It is what I expected to have atleast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Its all about searching...

  Found answer @ https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/20

  you can also read more about it @
  https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

For anybody interested:
Below is my adaptation of the code, which will replace the while Loop in client.py

```
current = set()

def on_press(key):
    send(str(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        listener.stop()

def on_release(key):
    try:
        current.remove(key)
    except KeyError:
        pass

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```